# Accessing other methods of an anonymous class from a lambda passed as parameter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's say I have a method that creates an anonymous object and store it somewhere. This anonymous object calls lambdas in its methods, that have been passed as parameters.

```
public class myCallBackManager {

    private List<MyCallBack<?>> callBackList = new LinkedList<MyCallBack<?>>();

    public <T> void addCallBack(Consumer<MyCallBack<T> onCall, Runnable something){
        callBackList.add(new MyCallback<T>() {
            @Override
            protected void call(MyCallback<T> callback) {
                onCall.accept(callback);
            }
            @Override
            protected void doSomething() {
                something.run());
            }
        }
    }

    public void runAll() {
        for (MyCallback<?> myCallback : callBackList) {
            myCallback.call();
        }
    }
}
```

This stores the objects internally and ask for them to all be executed at once later.

But then, I want to add this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable someRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Doing something");

    MyCallBackManager myCallBackManager = new MyCallbackManager();
    myCallBackManager.<SomeObject> addCallback(
            (callback) -> {
                doSomething(); // WON'T WORK
                System.out.println(callback.toString());
            },
            someRunnable
    };

    myCallBackManager.runAll();

}
```

Here, I am trying to call doSomething() from the onCall lambda as it is run by the call() of the anonymous function as it is called. The problem is, I don't have a handle on still non-existant object where this will happen, so obviously it won't be able to call its methods. Is there a way to call doSomething() from the lambda?

There are workarounds in this particular case, for example calling someRunnable.run() instead of trying to access the doSomething() method, but I am asking specifically to a way to call the method instead.

Comment: You have several strange things in your code: `MyCallback` and `MyCallBack`, `MyCallBack` as raw type, `MyCallBackManager myCallBackManager = new MyCallbackManager;` – which is not valid. Is this your real code?

Comment: @MCEmperor No, my real code has more stuff and I tried to keep things to what was relevant. It is using generics, so no raw type there. I will edit it, though. Also oops for the instantiation, good catch.

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly. Since you haven't provided the source of the `MyCallback` class, for instance, it is not quite clear what you want. I somehow got the feeling you have complicated things for a relatively simple task.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. What are you really trying to do?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Test {

    public static class MyCallback<T> {

        public void call() {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.call()");           
        }

        protected void call(MyCallback<?> callback) {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.call(MyCallback<?>)");          
        }

        protected void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.doSomething()");            
        }

    }

    static public class CallBackManager {

        private List<MyCallback<?>> callBackList = new LinkedList<>();

        public void addCallBack(Consumer<MyCallback<?>> onCall, Runnable something){
            callBackList.add(new MyCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                protected void call(MyCallback callback) {
                    onCall.accept(callback);
                }
                @Override
                protected void doSomething() {
                    something.run();
                }
            }
                    );
        }

        public void runAll() {
            for (MyCallback<?> myCallback : callBackList) {
                myCallback.call();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable someRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Doing something");

        CallBackManager myCallBackManager = new CallBackManager();
        myCallBackManager.addCallBack(
                (MyCallback<?> callback) -> {
                    callback.doSomething(); // WON'T WORK
                    System.out.println(callback.toString());
                },
                someRunnable
                );

        myCallBackManager.runAll();

    }

}
```

you never use onCall in Test.CallBackManager.addCallBack(Consumer>, Runnable) maybe that is the problem also.

Or are you trying this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Test {

    public static class MyCallback<T> {

        public void call() {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.call()");           
        }

        protected void call(MyCallback<?> callback) {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.call(MyCallback<?>)");          
        }

        protected void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.doSomething()");            
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            System.out.println("Test.MyCallback.toString()");           
            return "[CLASS Test.MyCallback<T>]";
        }

    }

    static public class CallBackManager {

        private List<MyCallback<?>> callBackList = new LinkedList<>();

        public void addCallBack(Consumer<MyCallback<?>> onCall, Runnable something){
            callBackList.add(new MyCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                protected void call(MyCallback callback) {
                    onCall.accept(callback);
                }
                @Override
                protected void doSomething() {
                    something.run();
                }
            }
                    );
        }

        public void runAll() {
            for (MyCallback<?> myCallback : callBackList) {
                myCallback.call();
                myCallback.call(myCallback);//OR THIS?
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable someRunnable = () -> System.out.println("Doing something");

        CallBackManager myCallBackManager = new CallBackManager();
        myCallBackManager.addCallBack(
                (MyCallback<?> callback) -> {
                    callback.doSomething(); // WON'T WORK
                    System.out.println(callback.toString());
                },
                someRunnable
                );

        myCallBackManager.runAll();

    }

}
```